# File browser GUI to read the filepath

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, pysimplegui

I have to plot a graph using matplotlib by reading a CSV file from pandas. Furthermore, I need to enter the file path outside the python code instead of entering inside the `pd.read_csv('file path)`. So for that to happen, I need to create a GUI using the PySimpleGUI module. But I'm stuck in the middle of not taking the filename inside the program. The full code is given below:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme("DarkTeal2")
layout = [[sg.T("")], [sg.Text("Choose a file: "), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse(key="-IN-")],[sg.Button("Submit")]]

###Building Window
window = sg.Window('My File Browser', layout, size=(600,150))
    
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event=="Exit":
        break
    elif event == "Submit":
        print(values["-IN-"])
```

**This is the code for the dialogue box**

The code for my plotting is as follows :

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
#Reading the CSV file
ds = pd.read_csv(r"filename.csv")

#Input of required value of time
start_row = int(input('Please enter starting time(in ms): '))
end_row =int(input('Please enter ending time(in ms): '))

if start_row>end_row or start_row==end_row :
    print("Please Enter the end time greater than the start time!")


else:
#Plotting of the graph
    print(plt.plot(ds.iloc[start_row:(end_row+1)]))
    plt.xlabel('Milliseconds')
    plt.ylabel('TCMD')
    plt.grid()
    plt.savefig(r"path")    #To save the plot as a jpeg file
    plt.show()
    ds.describe()

#Detailed insights on the data
print(ds.iloc[start_row:(end_row+1)].describe())
```

Please help me out with a solution.

Comment: `[sg.Text("Choose a file: "), sg.Input(key="-IN-"), sg.FileBrowse()],`, get `filename = values['-IN-']` after you click button `Submit`, after window close, then `ds = pd.read_csv(filename)`.

Comment: I had tried that already but there is an error showing values is not defined

Comment: What the full error message ?

Comment: NameError: name 'values' is not defined

Comment: Maybe the code not same as you posted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code to get filename, or you can call `filename = sg.popup_get_file("Choose a file: ", file_types=(("ALL CSV Files", "*.csv"), ("ALL Files", "*.*"), ))` directly.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg


sg.theme("DarkTeal2")

layout = [
    [sg.T("")],
    [sg.Text("Choose a file: "),
     sg.Input(key="-IN-"),
     sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("ALL CSV Files", "*.csv"), ("ALL Files", "*.*"), ))],
    [sg.Button("Submit")],
]

window = sg.Window('My File Browser', layout, size=(600,150))

filename = ""
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, "Exit"):
        break
    elif event == "Submit":
        filename = values['-IN-']
        break

window.close()
print(filename)
```